# How to run node commands from vscode

Tags: node.js

I've installed node and npm. I'm able to run node apps from Windows cmd but when I try using the vscode terminal, it says node is not recognized as an internal or external command. Please help me fix this

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you need to set the node.js folder path into system variables or user variables.

1. open Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables
2. in "User variables" or "System variables" find variable `PATH` and add node.js folder path as value. Usually it is `C:\Program Files\nodejs;`. If a variable doesn't exist, create it.
3. Restart your IDE or computer.

It is useful to add also "npm" and "Git" paths as variable, separated by a semicolon.